# How to install dynamic_reconfigure generated header file

Tags: dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add a dynamic_reconfigure server to my node. `catkin_make` is successful, including the generation of the .h file for my .cfg file, but `catkin_make install` generates the error:

`file INSTALL cannot find "/devel/include/customConfigFile.h"`

The `customConfigFile.h` is generated in my package, but is not ever moved over to devel/. I could not find anything relevant mentioned in the dynamic_reconfigure tutorials. How should I install the generated header file?

I'm running Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203700/how-to-install-dynamic_reconfigure-generated-header-file/) by [bgoldfai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2600/bgoldfai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue some time ago.

Headers (and Python files) generated by `dynamic_reconfigure` have their install rules auto-generated as well (see [dynamic_reconfigure-macros.cmake, lines 52 and 53](https://github.com/ros/dynamic_reconfigure/blob/de0aa1cf2b4b96234de8c23c0d877d3c1fa9da70/cmake/dynamic_reconfigure-macros.cmake#L52-L53)).

The name for the files is set some lines earlier (just the cpp line here):

```
set(_output_cpp ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}/${_cfgonly}Config.h)
```

If I remember correctly, I had an error in my `.cfg` file: the third parameter of the `gen.generate(..)` call did not match the filename of my `.cfg`. This led the CMake macro to generate a wrong filename (I had double `ConfigConfig.h`), causing the `cannot find ..` error upon installing.

You might want to make sure all the names you specified are consistent with actual and generated filenames.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bgoldfai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2600/bgoldfai/) on 2015-02-24**:
Thanks I went through all the parameters in my .cfg file again and found a capitalization error in one. Successfully installs now.